# JSON obj to dynamic multi dimensional arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an JSON obj:

```
 { 'A' : [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C': [7,8,9] }
```

I need to create multiple javascript arrays each to store

```
[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
```

separately.
The JSON obj can have many such entires as it depends on what returns from SQL database, so the arrays has to be created dynamically.
Please tell how to do this.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: i think the expected output he want should be an double array.

Comment: @Dean for example?

Comment: So do you want a JavaScript or php solution?

Comment: `[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]` he did mention it at the question

Comment: @Dean,well,i mean output is three arrays or one array? [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] or [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

Comment: @xianshenglu `the arrays has to be created dynamically` that he said

Comment: I need expected output like this: arr1=[1,2,3] ; arr2=[4,5,6] ; arr3=[7,8,9] which i think is not possible, so multi dimensional arrays could solve but Im not sure how this is done?

Comment: I need to refer to the arrays individually as I need to use them in my HighCharts.

Comment: @ravikumar If you know exactly how many subarrays you will have in the multidimensional array, then you can use a [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment): `const [one, two, three] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];`

Answer (score 4):

#### ✨ ES2017's [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

If support is not a problem, this can't be more concise!

```js
const object = { A: [1,2,3], B: [4,5,6], C: [7,8,9] };

console.log(Object.values(object));
```

#### ES5 [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

If you need better browser support, I would use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) together with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (ES5 if you change the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for a normal function and the `const` for a `var`):

```js
const object = { A: [1,2,3], B: [4,5,6], C: [7,8,9] };
  
console.log(Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]));
```

#### ES5 [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Otherwise, another approach with ES5 might be to use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Longer to write, but probably faster (?)

```js
var object = { A: [1,2,3], B: [4,5,6], C: [7,8,9] };
var listOfLists = [];

for (const key in object)
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(key))
    listOfLists.push(object[key]);
  
console.log(listOfLists);
```

#### [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) VS [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

As stated [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), the difference between [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is that the former will not consider properties in the prototype chain (so you don't need the `object.hasOwnProperty(key)` check).

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Comment: This pretty much works, but is there a way where i could say arr['A'] and output would be [1,2,3], arr['B'] and output would be [4,5,6] etc. like key-value pairs?

Comment: @ravikumar You can just use the object you had initially. In any of my examples, it would be just `object.A` or `object['A']`, and you will get `[1, 2, 3]`. If you have a JSON `string` representation of it instead of an actual `Object`, you can convert it just by doing: `const object = JSON.parse('{ "A" : [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C": [7,8,9] }')`

Answer (score 1):

i hope this is what you want:

```
let obj = { 'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9] };
let result = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce(function(result, property) {
    result.push(obj[property]);
    return result;
}, []);
console.log(result);//[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```